# script for generating html template

Tags: html

I'm looking for open source html template script.Say there are some template,people will choose one then they'ii be allowed to edit title and insert some content in body.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

[Themeforest](http://themeforest.net/) has huge collection. They are paid resources though.